# How to distribute overround over probabilities?

Tags: probability, gambling

Is there any common pattern for distributing overround over the initial probabilities in bookmaking? Or it's up to bookmaker and they usually don't share it?

UPD:

Suppose we have some event with n possible outcomes and probability of $i$-th outcome is $p_i$. The "fair" prices are calcullated as $k_i = 1/p_i$. But bookmakers understate "fair" prices. Which is why if having bookmaker price $k_{i}^{'}$ for i-th outcome we obtain probablity as $p_{i}^{'} = 1/k_{i}^{'}$ and summing this probabilities we get something more than 1. So the overround = $\sum p_i - 1$. My question is: is there any common pattern (algorithm) to distribute this overround over initial probabilities $p_i$ to get implied probabilities $p_{i}^{'}$. Or how do the bookmakers exactly calculate prices having initial outcome probabilities? is such calculations common for all of them or it's unique and in private?

PS: can have some grammatical mistakes :(

Comment: could you clarify?

Comment: +1 This is the first question I have seen that clearly explains the gambling terminology.

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_bookmaking and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parimutuel_betting at least as a starting point for further investigation?